# BroadcastReceiver onReceive method called before Fragment onCreate()

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I have an IntentService which starts when SplashActivity onCreate called :

```
class SplashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)
        startService(Intent(applicationContext, ContactsService::class.java))
        handler.postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }, SPLASH_DELAY.toLong())
    }
}

private const val SPLASH_DELAY = 1500
```

Here is my IntentService :

```
override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        val cursor = ContactUtil.getContactsCursor(null, null, this)
        val contacts = ContactUtil.getContacts(cursor, this)
        cursor?.close()
        val contactsIntent = Intent(CONTACTS_RECEIVER)
        contactsIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(CONTACTS, ArrayList<Parcelable>(contacts))
        sendBroadcast(contactsIntent)
    }
```

1 - If I have huge number of contacts, my broadcastReceiver `onReceive` method called after Fragment creation, which is ok.

2 - If I have a few number of fragment, `onReceive` method called before Fragment creation, which does not update my UI at all.

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            List<Contact> contacts = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra(CONTACTS);
            mContacts = contacts;
            mAdapter.setItems(contacts, true);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mAppBarLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
```

What is the solution for 2nd case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by getting rid of the system broadcast. Assuming your code does what is described, **you are leaking all the user's contacts to every single app on the device**. So, beyond the performance problems and the chance of crashing the app with a too-big `Intent`, you have a major privacy hole.

Then, get rid of the `IntentService`. It is deprecated, and it is unnecessary if all you are doing with this data is using it in a UI.

Instead, set up a singleton repository that manages your access to the contacts. Have your activity's `ViewModel` call some method on the repository to do that, where the repository uses an ordinary background thread (perhaps through an `Executor` or RxJava type). The repository can emit an event when the work is completed, such as via `LiveData` or RxJava. Your `ViewModel` can use `LiveData` for letting the UI layer know about the data so it can update the UI. And, since `LiveData` is a value holder, it will hold the value even if the value arrives before the fragment is ready for it.

This approach (repository object with a reactive API) is part of Google's general architecture recommendations.

Comment: [I have an implementation for that in master branch](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/viewmodels/ContactsViewModel.kt). Should I move my RxJava request to repository singleton? Should I keep my LiveData in ViewModel? Can I call my RxJava request  in repository singleton from SplashActivity?

Comment: @ali: "Can I call my RxJava request from SplashActivity?" -- I would use a `ViewModel` as an intermediary, if you are doing this from an activity. "I have an implementation for that in master branch" -- FWIW, your code there does not appear to be doing the work on a scheduler. `Observable.just()` does its work immediately. "Should I move my RxJava request to repository singleton?" -- if you need this data across multiple activities, yes. "Should I keep my LiveData in ViewModel?" -- it's a convenient approach, though there are ways to skip it and use RxJava all the way to the fragment.

Comment: composeObservable is a method in my [BaseViewModel](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/Service/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/viewmodels/BaseViewModel.kt) which includes `Observable.just()` statement. I want `ContactUtil.getContacts` starts to execute as soon as SplashActivity onCreate called and show the result in MainActivity as soon as result is available. Do I need multiple viewModels for every Activity?

Comment: @Ali: "Do I need multiple viewModels for every Activity?" -- I can't answer that. You can have multiple viewmodels if you want (e.g., for reuse).

Comment: I don't get how to I execute ContactUtil.getContacts as soon as SplashActivity onCreate called and show the result in MainActivity as soon as result is available. LiveData is in [MainViewModel](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/Service/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/viewmodels/ContactsViewModel.kt) Can I create two instances of viewModel in both Activities? I don't think that works.

Comment: @Ali: "I don't get how to I execute ContactUtil.getContacts as soon as SplashActivity onCreate called and show the result in MainActivity as soon as result is available." -- if you want to use the data across multiple activities, you need to use a repository to load the data. Your viewmodels can talk to the repository.

Comment: I have modified my app by [Repository](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/Service/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/ContactsRepository.kt), [SplashViewModel](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/Service/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/viewmodels/SplashViewModel.kt) and [SplashActivity](https://github.com/Ali-Rezaei/Contacts/blob/Service/app/src/main/java/com/sample/android/contact/ui/SplashActivity.kt) Are they what you recommended in your answer?

Comment: @Ali: In terms of roles, yes. Just note that `Observable.just(ContactUtil.getContacts(cursor, context))` is going to do its work *on the current thread*, and so it will freeze your UI.

Comment: Thanks again. What is the solution?

Comment: @Ali: [`Observable.create()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#create-io.reactivex.ObservableOnSubscribe-) would be a typical solution.

Comment: Great help. Thanks a lot.